# json schema validation not enforcing type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a column that stores json. I am trying to make sure that only an array of objects can be stored in this column as described in the json schema below. The schema is working except for that I am able to save the attribute `show` as a string when it should be forced to be a boolean.  For example, `[{"name"=>"primary_phone", "show"=> "some text"}]` is saving correctly but it shouldn't.  How do I enforce that show must be a boolean?

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "definitions": {
        "name": { "type": "string" },
        "show": {"type": "boolean"}
    },
    "required": ["name", "show"]
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Framework challenge: if the data you're storing in a JSON column has a defined schema then why on earth are you using a JSON column in the first place? You know whats self validating? A database table.

Comment: That would be a has_many/belongs_to relationship and would be inefficient for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thats almost certainly a case of premature optimization that never actually pans out. If anything JSON columns tend to lead to very slow queries since its harder to index the data properly and it leads to denormalization.

Comment: I don't need to query based on the json data. I just need to fetch it.

Comment: Suit yourself - a JSON schema validator is not a built for this though and not a good guarantee for the consistency of your data as it's on the application level.

Comment: a json schema validator is not built for validating json schema?

Comment: It's built for validating that the input/output from an API adheres to the specification. If you use it to try to guarantee consistency of your database data you're in for a big letdown. It's in no way a suitable replacement for db constraints and sensible relational modeling.

Comment: JSON Schemas aren't just for APIs. Using it for validation on storage is a perfectly fine use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema under "items" is invalid. Perhaps you meant "properties" instead of "definitions"?